# Get specific value from a .file in JS

Tags: javascript

I've got a  file .config:

```
login = "toto"
password = "tata"
```

I want to display only the value after equal and stock it into a variable like:

```
console.log(firstVariable); //toto 
console.log(secondVariable); //tata
```

What i'm doing:

```
const text = fs.readFileSync("/home/.config", "utf-8").trim());
var textByLine = text.split("\n")
console.log(textByLine); 
// [ 'login = "toto";','password = "tata";' ]
```

How can I continue ?

Comment: Loop over the lines, split them at the `=` sign, then remove the quotes from the second part to get the value.

Comment: I suggest you change the format of the config file to JSON, then you can just use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Yeah it's possible to do in JSON but I'm trying to do with .file

Comment: if you change the format to `.env` then you can use npm package `dotenv` to parse.
`require('dotenv').config({ path: '/.env' })` and access value by `process.env.KEY_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Run a for loop, split it based on equals sign followed by removing the quotes and then semicolon.

```js
var arr = ['login = "toto";', 'password = "tata";'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var splitResult = arr[i].split("=");
  var expectedValue = splitResult[1].replace(/["']/g, "").slice(0, -1);
  console.log(expectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I need two variable with different output. In your help, got only one variable

Comment: May be add it to an object, then get the properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Just place after the line where you split your text.

```js
var textByLine = [ 'login = "toto";','password = "tata";' ]

var login, password;
textByLine.forEach(item => {
  var arr = item.split(" = ");
  if(arr[0] === "login") {
    login=arr[1].replace("\"", "").replace("\";", "");
  } else { 
    password=arr[1].replace("\"", "").replace("\";", "");
  }
});

console.log(login);
console.log(password);
```